# Вопрос про псевдослучайные числа и теорию вероятностей

Tags: java, случайные-числа, теория-вероятностей

Программа генерирует псевдослучайные целые числа в диапазоне от 1 до 5. Найти вероятную частоту выпадения серии из 5 одинаковых чисел.
В теории это значение 1/625, но на практике в программе получается примерно 1/780 на миллиарде случайных чисел. Почему так? Для генерации использую java библиотеку Math и метод random():
`

```
        int a = 1; // от
        int b = 5; // до
        int number;
        int quantity = 1; // число подряд идущих одинаковых чисел
        int n = 0; // число серий из 5 одинаковых чисел
        int previous = a + (int) (Math.random() * b);

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {

            number = a + (int) (Math.random() * b);

            if(number == previous) {
                quantity++;
            } else {
                quantity = 1;
            }

            if(quantity == 5) {
                n++;
                quantity = 1;
            }

            previous = number;
        }

        System.out.println("Число повторов: " + n); //1280
```

`

Comment: Ваша программа не учитывает, что последовательности из 5 одинаковых чисел могут перекрываться. В последовательности `1 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 2` она найдет только 1 повтор.

Comment: все, я понял свою ошибку, спасибо, в последнем условии заменить 'quantity == 5' на 'quantity >= 5'

Comment: Тоже не подойдёт. В коммерции выше приведен пример и в нем 5 таких посдедовательностей

Comment: Нужно искать длину последовательности из 5. Тогда количество будет длина-4

Comment: Как только число одинаковых элементов равно 5, то с каждым следующим повторением появляется ещё одна последовательность из 5 элементов. Например: 55555 5, тут уже 2 можно составить (с 1 по 5 и с 2 по 6).

Comment: Вот ещё: 55555 5 5, тут уже 3(1-5, 2-6, 3-7) тоесть каждое новое повторение >5 это +1 последовательность. К тому же в таком случае программа показывает такие же данные что и по теории вероятностей, а именно 160000 совпадений из 100 миллионов, тоесть каждые 625 генераций